# C# Drag and Drop Effect with Overlay/Opaque Image

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, overlay

I think this would be simple question and should be asked in the pas few years but unable to google around and dont know if there is a specific keyword.

In c# WinForm I want to do drag and drop but I dont want the image of DragDropEffects Move, Copy or whatever. I want to display an image with half opaque. Just like Firefox when dragging an image, you would see the image folowing the mouse pointer like a ghost :)

I already Implement DoDragDrop, DragEnter and DragDrop events. I just want to customize the dragging effects with overlay image.

Answer (score 0):

Might be 9 years too late to the party

I always liked Drag&Drop interactions but found it complicated to use in WinForms. Especially if you want it to look professional with overlays.

I made my own library for WinForms the last time I needed Drag&Drop. You can find it here or on NuGet:

- https://github.com/awaescher/FluentDragDrop

[image: Drag and Drop operations with FluentDragDrop]

Here's everything you need to implement Drag&Drop like shown above:

```
private void picControlPreviewBehindCursor_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pic = (PictureBox)sender;

    pic.InitializeDragAndDrop()
        .Copy()
        .Immediately()
        .WithData(pic.Image)
        .WithPreview().BehindCursor()
        .To(PreviewBoxes, (target, data) => target.Image = data);

    // Copy(), Move() or Link() to define allowed effects
    // Immediately() or OnMouseMove() for deferred start on mouse move
    // WithData() to pass any object you like
    // WithPreview() to define your preview and how it should behave
    //     BehindCursor() or RelativeToCursor() to define the preview placement
    // To() to define target controls and how the dragged data should be used on drop
}
```